What are the industry-standard state machine libraries for ROS 2?
I’m working on a research project where I am exploring different state machine libraries for ROS 2 to manage robot behaviors. I have come across libraries such as SMACH, SMACC, and FlexBE, but I would like the community’s take on which ones are commonly used in the industry.
Code examples demonstrating how you use your chosen library would be greatly appreciated or some open-source projects.

There is also Yasmin, but it is GPL so for sure not "commonly used in the industry".
